# HUT WIRE IN GERMANIUM

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I stumbled across a paper referring to "hut wire" which seems to be something in Germanium and something to do with quantum dots. No response by Googling hut wire.

What is this all about, please

Comment: See https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.nanolett.6b02715 for a description of the physical situation.

Comment: Googling "germanium quantum dots hut" got things rolling...

Comment: I got responses from: Germanium hut wire